# Android Device Monitor/DDMS can't connect to device over network

Tags: android-studio, adb, ddms

I am trying to debug a memory leak on a Android based VOIP desk phone with Android Studio 2.1 (For what it's worth it's a Grandstream GXV3275 phone, which has a 7in Android tablet embedded in it).

As best I can tell this device has no direct USB connection. I've enabled "Developer Mode" on the phone and am able to connect to it using "adb connect" from the command line. I can use Android Studio to then download and run/debug applications over the network.

But Android Device Monitor will not connect to the device and the phone does not show up in Device Monitor's list of devices. In the Device Monitor's console i see:

[2016-08-30 15:17:32 - DeviceMonitor] Adb connection Error:EOF

[2016-08-30 15:17:32 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 1

[2016-08-30 15:17:33 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 2

[2016-08-30 15:17:34 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 3

Any ideas how to make Device Monitor recognize devices over the network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the alternative is to use the Android Monitor tab built into Android Studio. This does indeed seem to work without a direct usb tether. Android Monitor supports initiating GC and performing heap dumps (HPROF). The downside that I have seen, is that performing an HPROF dump temporarily disconnects my ethernet connected Android desktop phone from the network.